# How to edit 1st column in Project Structure in PyCharm 2021.1.1?

Tags: python, pycharm, project-structure

For my project in PyCharm, the Project Structure looks like this :

[image]

So my question is, **what is this 1st column (marked with red color) in Project Structure is for and how I can edit that column??**

That column is showing some names that are of no use to my Project so only I want to either delete all the content of that column or edit content of that column at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened in this case is that you have **one project** with multiple projects opened in the same window (a 1 to N relationship of projects) - this was done using the "Attach" option in [Open multiple projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/open-projects.html#d9b204f2).

The problem is that the [Project Settings files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-and-ide-settings.html#project_settings) hold references to 2 projects (`Rest framework` and `Restframework`) that have been moved/deleted and cannot be found. The IDE indicates there's an error because it shows no files in the 2nd column (there should at least be an `.idea` folder for each of the 2 referenced projects) but it still shows the outdated references that are in its settings files.

> how I can edit that column??

You are not supposed to edit the column in this case. Projects are supposed to be added and removed using the Project Tool Window (in `View` `>` `Tool Windows` `>` `Project` or <kbd>Alt + 1</kbd>, also show in this screenshot: [Delete a project from view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/open-projects.html#delete-from-view)). But because of the error the projects aren't being shown in the "Project Tool Window" (which makes it difficult to delete the problematic projects now).

The easiest way is deleting the `.idea` folder (make a backup just in case) and [Open your project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/open-projects.html#open-local-project) using `File` `>` `Open` (And this time use the "This Window" option in [Open multiple projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/open-projects.html#d9b204f2)). This will force the IDE to recreate fresh project settings directory/files and will solve the problem.

Comment: Among the 2 choices you gave the first one worked for me and thank u so much for that but the second choice is not right I guess as Project Structure is a setting which is specified for a specific project so can't be edited from the IDE settings and if u agree with that please remove that part from the answer as it will make the answer ideal

Comment: @PrateekGupta ok I removed that part, no problem.